# Unable to add @spartacus/schematics@5.2.0 even angular, node and yarn versions are maintained as mentioned in pre-requisites

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I have maintained the required versions as given below:
Angular CLI: 14.2.10
Node: 14.15.5
Yarn: 1.22.19

have created the angular application as well.

But When I run this command: ng add @spartacus/schematics@5.2.0
I am getting following error: Unable to fetch package information for '@spartacus/schematics@5.2.0': No matching version found for @spartacus/schematics@5.2.0.

I was expecting it to work like proper spartacus 5.2.0 application as mentioned in this SAP page

https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_COMMERCE_COMPOSABLE_STOREFRONT/cfcf687ce2544bba9799aa6c8314ecd0/5de67850bd8d487181fef9c9ba59a31d.html

Comment: Did you have any luck?

Answer (score 0):

Please add .npmrc file into your appfolder

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).